# SQL: Select column names based on column value as a list and append as a separate column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For each row in a table, I want to select names of some specific columns where column value is not null and append those column names as a list of characters as a separate column. I'm working on Big Query views.

I have a column like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | Null | 2.0 |
| 1.0 | Null | 1.1 |
| 4.5 | 3.5 | Null |
| Null | 3.5 | Null |

I want to select only names of columns A, C, if they have a non-null value. In short, an output like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Null | 2.4 | 2.0 | C |
| 1.0 | Null | 1.1 | A, C |
| 4.5 | 3.5 | Null | A |
| Null | 3.5 | Null | Null |

There may be multiple specific columns with non-nulls and I want to pick them all and show as a list.

Will be grateful for any help!

Comment: this is not appreciated here on SO, if you update the question that already has answer(s) - this can invalidate such answer(s)!

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I'll certainly take care of this from future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select *, 
  array_to_string(
    regexp_extract_all(
      regexp_replace(trim(to_json_string(t), '{}'), r'"[^"]+":null,?', ''), 
    r'"([^"]+)":'),
  ',') as List
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

In case if yo need to exclude some columns from being enlisted - use below approach

```
select *, (
  select string_agg(col) 
  from unnest(
    regexp_extract_all(
      regexp_replace(trim(to_json_string(t), '{}'), r'"[^"]+":null,?', ''), 
      r'"([^"]+)":')) as col
  where not col in ('B')
  ) as List
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Very very grateful. Might I ask as a novice, how to generalise in the case where there are many columns and I want to pick names of only some specific columns (say, P, Q, R) if they have a non-null value. The specific columns P, Q, R can lie anywhere in the sequence of columns in table. As a test case, let us suppose, columns are sequenced as Col1, P, Col2, Col3, Q, Col4, R, Col5.

Comment: see added example  - you should put the list of such columns to be excluded in following line - `where not col in ('P', 'Q', 'R')` or if you want to include only those columns  - use  `where col in ('P', 'Q', 'R')`

Comment: Mikhail, I get nulls when I run this. I carefully checked there are clear non-null cols which are not captured. Till the stage when regexp_replace() function is called, I can nicely see details of all non-null cols for each row. But the moment I apply regexp_extract_all() on the previous output, I lose all information and I get alternate rows of just ':' and ','. Might there be any issues with the last argument in regexp_extract_all()? Apologies for the presumption, and thanks for teaching so much through this.

Comment: try again. there was a typo in that last argument, so I updated answer

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem completely. and taught me new things along the way!